# What's wrong with my Dynamic Programming solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm doing some HackerRank problems. I'm completely new to leetcode and concepts like Dynamic Programming. Could you point out what I did wrong in my DP-recursive solution? I'm failing the test cases because of time-complexity.

The HackerRank problem is Longest Palindromic Subsequence, where a string is passed as the parameter, and the subsequences (substrings that are found by deleting characters; not permutations) are evaluated to see if they're a palindrome, and then the length of the longest subsequence is returned. I figured a recursive solution would work well to find all of the possible subsequences; I tried implementing DP, but it still seems to be really slow.

```
"""
checks if the string is a palindrome by listing it and then checking 
if it's equal to its reversed list
"""

def is_palindrome(string):
    str_list = list(string)
    return str_list == [ele for ele in reversed(str_list)]

"""
recursive wrapper function that takes in a dict for memoization 
"""

def longest_palindrome(string, dict):
    if string in dict:
        return dict[string]

    if len(string) == 1:
        return True

    if is_palindrome(string):
        dict[string] = True
    else:
        dict[string] = False

    for index in range(0, len(string)):
        subsequence = string[:index] + string[index + 1:]
        dict[subsequence] = longest_palindrome(subsequence, dict)

    return dict[string]

"""
required function that returns length of longest palindrome in dict-memo. 
I saved each subsequence here and kept the value as T/F. iterated through
the dictionary for the longest key (subsequence) that also had a T value.
"""
def longestPalindromeSubseq(string):
    new_dict = {}
    longest_palindrome(string, new_dict)

    long_pal = 0
    for key, value in new_dict.items():
        if value and len(key) > long_pal:
            long_pal = len(key)

    return long_pal


print(longestPalindromeSubseq("bdbfbfbajjfbb")) ## output is 7, palindrome = 'bfbfbfb'
```

Comment: Your code is creating many lists, with slicing, `+` operator, `list()`, `[ ... reversed()]`... this makes it slow. Try to just do this with character by character comparisons without actually creating sublists.

Comment: What is also wrong: The docstrings should be in the first line after the function's signature within its body, not before it.

Comment: @RichardNeumann Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't know about that convention. I threw those in there just on StackOverflow for clarification.

Comment: @trincot Thank you for the suggestion. I'll find some more efficient ways of doing those. As far as the DP logic goes, was it correct?

Comment: A dictionary keyed by (potentially) long strings is not the most efficient. It will be more efficient to use start/end indices inside the string as the keys in your DP variable. So either a 2-dimensional list (one for the start index, the other for the end index). This way it will work. However, there  are even more advanced ways which use just a one-dimensional list.